# Not able to set success URL in Apache Shiro

Tags: java, tomcat, jakarta-ee, tomcat7, shiro

I was trying to use Apache Shiro as a security framework to secure my web application. While doing that I wanted to set the success URL that a user is redirected to after successful login. By default the client gets redirected to the originally requested page after successful login (mentioned in the API).

https://shiro.apache.org/static/1.2.1/apidocs/src-html/org/apache/shiro/web/filter/authc/AuthenticationFilter.html

My question is, can we change this default behaviour and redirect the user to a particular success page on login?

From what I know, we can mention this in the shiro.ini file

```
authc.successUrl  = /personalaccountpage.html
```

where authc is the implicit object provided in shiro enabled applications. But this doesn't seem to be picked by the application. The user is always redirected to the requested URL.

I know this is illogical saying I want to redirect the user to some other page even though user requested a particular page, but then I would like to understand the purpose of the configuration provided to us given below :

authc.successUrl

I am using Apache Shiro 1.2.4 and Tomcat 7 as the Container for my web application.

Here are the main files involed here:

**shiro.ini file**

```
# =============================================================================
# Tutorial INI configuration
#
# Usernames/passwords are based on the classic Mel Brooks' film "Spaceballs" :)
# =============================================================================


[main]

# specify login page
authc.loginUrl = /login.jsp

# redirect after successful login
authc.successUrl  = /personalaccountpage.html

# name of request parameter with username; if not present filter assumes 'username'
authc.usernameParam = user
# name of request parameter with password; if not present filter assumes 'password'
authc.passwordParam = pass
# does the user wish to be remembered?; if not present filter assumes 'rememberMe'
authc.rememberMeParam = remember

# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Users and their (optional) assigned roles
# username = password, role1, role2, ..., roleN
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[users]
root = secret, admin
guest = guest, guest
presidentskroob = 12345, president
darkhelmet = ludicrousspeed, darklord, schwartz
lonestarr = vespa, goodguy, schwartz

# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Roles with assigned permissions
# roleName = perm1, perm2, ..., permN
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[roles]
admin = *
schwartz = lightsaber:*
goodguy = winnebago:drive:eagle5

[urls]
/**=authc
```

**web.xml of my webapp**

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
          http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    version="2.5">

    <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.apache.shiro.web.env.EnvironmentLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>ShiroFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.ShiroFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>ShiroFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
        <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
        <dispatcher>INCLUDE</dispatcher>
        <dispatcher>ERROR</dispatcher>
    </filter-mapping>
</web-app>
```

**login.jsp page for my webapp. User redirected here for logging in when any URL requested**

```
    <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
        pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Please Log In</title>
    </head>
    <body>
<form name="loginform" action="" method="post">
        <table align="left" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3">
            <tr>
                <td>Username:</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="user" maxlength="30"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Password:</td>
                <td><input type="password" name="pass" maxlength="30"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2" align="left"><input type="checkbox" name="remember"><font size="2">Remember Me</font></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2" align="right"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Please let me know if I missed any detail.

Comment: Where did you put the shiro.ini file?

Comment: Hi @Wouter
My shiro.ini file is in WEB-INF

Answer (score 1):

You have to add

```
/login.jsp = authc
```

in your urls part of shiro.ini.

The /login.jsp is not restricted to authenticated users (otherwise no one could log in!), but the 'authc' filter must still be specified for it so it can process that url's login submissions. It is 'smart' enough to allow those requests through as specified by the shiro.loginUrl above.

Answer (score 0):

> **I would like to understand the purpose of the configuration
>   provided to us given below**

`authc.successUrl` is for user once he arrives from login page (it should be login.jsp and should also be welcome page generally for the application) with no url that he wanted to access. If you want to redirect to a static page anyway you can extend the original classes and do whatever you like.